# Join 3 tables and group movie results by user

Tags: mysql, left-join

My code so far:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c421c/6

I want to show all movies in the same row

Desired output:

```
|  Name| Favourite movies |
----------------------------
| Alice |          Movie A Movie B |
|   Bob |          Movie A Movie C |
| Carol |           (null) |
|  Dave |           (null) |
```

I'm using CodeIgniter 2 active record

PHP Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user] => Test
            [gender] => 0
            [GROUP_CONCAT(movies.movie SEPARATOR "-")] => Movie A-Movie B
        )
```

How should I print the output for the last field as I do with [user] (echo $user->user;)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`movies`.`movie`) AS "Favourite movies"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c421c/25)

you can also change the separator,

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`movies`.`movie` SEPARATOR ' ')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c421c/26)

---

- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT `users`.`user` AS name, 
       group_concat(`movies`.`movie`) AS favorites

FROM (`users`)

LEFT JOIN `users_movies` 
  ON `users`.`id` = `users_movies`.`user_id`

LEFT JOIN `movies` 
  ON `users_movies`.`movie_id` = `movies`.`id`

GROUP BY `users`.`user`
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c421c/27)